# Is there a way for an Android device to function as an NTRIP client?

Tags: java, android, network-protocols, ntrip, real-time-kinematic

I have an NTRIP caster that I'm supposed to communicate with from an Android application, via RTCM 3.0, to perform RTK.

Is there an Android or at least Java implementation of the NTRIP protocol available somewhere? I didn't find any that looked workable, and implementing the protocol myself doesn't seem feasible either, because even though it's just over HTTP, I couldn't find a specification for the NTRIP protocol.

Furthermore, can this be done without connecting an external GPS receiver to the device?

Answer (score 0):

The repo [api-ntrip-java-client](https://github.com/OneStopTransport/api-ntrip-java-client) contains what appears to contain the logic for the NTRIP protocol, along with a Bluetooth feed from a GPS NMEA device.   It should be possible to pick out what is needed.

A GPS receiver is not required if the NTRIP server does not require a $GGA location message, or the location can be obtained from a phone Geolocation API.

Applying the NTRIP corrections directly to improve a standard GPS accuracy requires an additional lib, and may not be possible from the standard Android Geolocation API.

Comment: What do you mean "Applying the NTRIP corrections directly to improve a standard GPS accuracy requires an additional lib"? As I understand I can send correction data received from NTRIP server to GPS device and all the corrections magic will happen there.